# REST API with flask structure and implementation approach

Tags: python, rest, flask

I recently started writing REST API, I wanted to have a proper structure of project and an approach which is more readable and make more sense interms of organising in a logical order. I took advantage of namespace and I have put endpoints of each name space into separate python package.

```
project
|______init__.py
|____api
| |______init__.py
| |____base
| | |______init__.py
| | |____resources.py
| |____hello
| | |______init__.py
| | |____resources.py
| |____routes.py
```

**project/__init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask 

def register_blueprints(app):
    # Since the application instance is now created, register each Blueprint
    # with the Flask application instance (app)
    from project.api import api_blueprint
    from project.api import base_api_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(api_blueprint)
    app.register_blueprint(base_api_blueprint)

def create_app(config_filename=None):
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.from_pyfile(config_filename)
    register_blueprints(app)
    return app
```

**project/api/__init__.py**

```
from flask import Blueprint

api_blueprint = Blueprint('api', __name__, template_folder='templates')
base_api_blueprint = Blueprint('base_api', __name__)

from . import routes
from .hello import resources
from .base import resources
```

**project/api/routes.py**

```
from flask_restplus import Resource

from . import api_blueprint, base_api_blueprint

base_api = Api(base_api_blueprint, catch_all_404s=True, prefix='/api', version='1.0', title='Sample API',
               description='A sample API',
               )

base_api.namespaces.pop(0)

base_api_ns = base_api.namespace('todos', description='base api namespace.')
hello_api_ns = base_api.namespace('hello', description='Hello World api.')
```

**project/api/base/resources.py**

```
from flask_restplus import Resource

from ..routes import base_api_ns

@base_api_ns.route('/base', endpoint='base-endpoint')
class BaseResource(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {"from": "base"}
```

**project/api/hello/resources.py**

```
from flask_restplus import Resource

from ..routes import hello_api_ns


@hello_api_ns.route('/world', endpoint='world-endpoint')
class BaseResource(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {"hello": "world"}
```

the rest api web app, has api that deals with two different type of tasks **base** and **hello** so I have segregated to a separate package and used different name space for each.

having a second [API](http://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.%E2%80%A6) object of `api_blueprint` would rather make more sense but that seems not work maybe due to a bug in flask restplus.
the swagger finally renders up like this:
[image]
Any input in implementation or improvement will be highly appreciated.